# Nginx+Node.js sometimes the request failes when the data to be retrived is big data (>15KB, 64KB)

Tags: node.js, nginx, request

I have a problem with google chrome and other browsers when retrieving a big data like 16KB or 64KB.. This doesn't happen all the time, but sometimes it happens and then happens even on refresh, I have to refresh about 5 times to make it work sometimes. And only happens with big data. So I don't really know what is the problem. I notice that it times out always at 1.1m.

In the network panel in developer mode when I don't click on any of the requests (general view) I can see my request with the method post (see image):

[image]

In nginx error logs it shows up something like this:

> 2012/11/05 12:05:36 [crit] 2344#0: *10327 open() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/3/16/0000000163"       failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.1.56, server: , request: "POST /production/assembly/rpc?nocache=1352117111478 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/rpc?nocache=1352117111478", host: "192.168.1.17", referrer: "http://192.168.1.17/production/assembly/"

I find this by `http://127.0.0.1:3000/rpc?nocache=1352117111478`, because the `1352117111478` part is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the folder "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/3/16/0000000163" has permissions only to www-data which is strange as no service (no nginx or node.js or mongodb) was run by www-data user. Anyway I found that changing the config in nginx: where was "user totty" I changed it to "user root" and it works everything!

I still don't understand why sometimes it worked and other didn't and why it correlates with the big data requests only. Maybe for those big data is cached or saved in some temp file and has no access.. Don't know but it works, for now.

Comment: Don't run nginx as root... run it as www-data or make totty own the folder.